# Need help in understanding Makefile for Kernel Module

Tags: linux-kernel, makefile, kernel-module

I am a newbie in Kernel Development. I was trying to understand the following makefile for Hello World! program. But I am not able to figure it out completely.

```
obj-m += hello.o


all:

    sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:

    sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I am not able to understand what is meant by 'obj-m += hello.o' . I know m here means module and thats it.

Also why are we not defining the dependencies of hello.o

And lastly I am not able to figure out completely the compiling rules defined under all: and clean:

Any help would be highly appreciated.!!

Answer (score 2):

`obj-m` is a Makefile variable. It actually consists of 2 parts: '*obj*' means that the referred target is a kernel object, while '*m*' part means that the object is to be build like a module.

The variable is considered by kernel build rules. As kernel modules follow a certain convention, running your Makefile will result in creation of module `hello.ko` from source file `hello.c` (if everything works properly).

The '*obj*' variable may take different suffixes as well. For example '*obj-y*' will try to link the referred object into the main kernel image, instead of creating a module. The suffix may also refer to a kernel `.config` file variable, like this:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_HOTPLUG) += hotplug.o
```

In this case, if `CONFIG_HOTPLUG` is set to '*y*' the hoplug object will be compiled into the main kernel; if set to 'm' then a separate `hotplug.ko` loadable module will be created. If not set to anything (resulting in '*obj-*'), hotplug will be omitted outright.